# Suggestion for movie in English (or subtitled in English) that shows a person modeling good/bad Buddhist behavior

Tags: learning-materials

I apologize in advance if this question is not in the scope of this SE.

Rather than read about the principles of Buddhism, I'd rather experience the practice of Buddhism through watching a movie.  Is there a movie that shows a character learning about Buddhism demonstrating good and bad behaviors as the character learns?  For example, something makes the character angry and the movie shows how the person reacts "in a Buddhist way" or reacts in a way that shows the outcome as it relates to Buddhist principles?

Preferable to be in the English language and entertaining for adults.

Comment: From the top of my head Samsara by nalin pan and spring summer autumn winter spring...

Comment: Related: [What are some entertaining/fictional movies, books, etc. about Buddhadharma or Buddha himself?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7359/254)

Comment: I think most of movies are relate to karma, to keep peoples' eyes on the movie. It's depending on the watcher karma analysis skill, PubbenivasAnussatiNana+CutUpapataNana, whether "which resultants are possible or not". **Karma is complicated depending on uncountable mind-moment (trillion times per second) through uncountable reborn**, so it's not easy to present on the show even for the Nana mastery.

Comment: Documentaries: dharma-documentaries.net has hundreds of documentaries, some in English, covering all schools of Buddhism and several related topics (like Shugendo). And fictional/semi-fictional films, not in English, but personally my favorite Buddhist movies are Spring Summer Fall Winter Spring, Why Has Bodhidharma Left For The East, The Burmese Harp, and Zen (2009 — you don't have to like modern Soto to appreciate this one).

Comment: Not a movie, but original greek stoicism comes quite close to buddhism in terms of action.

Comment: In terms of movie, I think the closes would be Jedi masters, yoda for example. They have overlapping ideology to buddhists.

Answer (score 0):

There is little Buddha with keano reeves playing Buddha (lol I know) which is more about Tibetan Buddhism and reincarnation of a Lhama with the Buddhas life story as a back drop.

Samsara, Tibetan movie so subtitles which is about a monk who cannot reconcile his desire for sex so goes into a family life but is always torn between both lifestyles.

Then there is seven years in Tibet which is a biographic movie about a german mountain climber who goes to Tibet during WW2. Bets movie of the 3 but only really has Buddhist influence rather than showing what Buddhist life is.

None of these are really what you are asking for except maybe the parts of Buddhas life in little Buddha but i honestly do not know of any actual movies that are Buddhist in nature that really explains the concepts of Buddhism. Kind of ironic that movies are idle entertainment so not really something a devout Buddhist practitioner would waste time on making and the actual Buddhas teachings do not translate into a movie like that, they are wisdom about reality not a fickle concept or story.

Answer (score 0):

There might be movies on "the life of the Buddha" out there, which can be assumed as the best sample behavior => buddhist behavior. But to simply follow his heir, the monks, would be of more use than to stay at home and watch movies, waste time by dreaming...

Answer (score 0):

I like this video of a Thai nun: [Perspective : ตามติดชีวิต ภิกษุณีธัมมทีปา | Wonder women [4 มิ.ย. 60] Full HD](https://youtu.be/ZULnEBpY35U?si=nUmfmn0JUgw3jj2N)